# Jest: unexpected token export with react-navigation

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

After spending two days in researching, I've finally run out of ideas.

The problem is a component that uses `withNavigation` from `React-Navigation`.

When I run `Jest`, it complains about an unexpected token export (React-Navigation), pointing `withNavigation`.

[image]

Since there is the same problem with other third-party libraries (such as `Native Base`), I concluded there must be a problem with `transformIgnorePatterns`. For example, I tried this [solution](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5686) among sooo many others, that are more or less similar. I also tried to adjust `babel.config`, as suggested in another post at GitHub. Nothing works! Maybe someone has any idea? Please not that I use `TypeScript`.

Here is the `Jest` part if my `package.json`:

```
  ...
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js",
      "\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.jest.json"
      }
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native|native-base|react-navigation|react-native-fabric)"
    ],
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$"
  }
```

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
};
```

tsconfig.jest.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ]
}
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
};
```

The component (Test):

```
imports ...

type Props = {}

const Test: React.FC<Props> = ({}) => {
  return (
    <View testID="test" style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Text testID="home">Home</Text>
        <ButtonNavigate title="Home" navigateTo="About" />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default withNavigation(Test);
```

And the test:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render, fireEvent} from 'react-native-testing-library';

import Test from '../Test';

// NativeAnimatedHelper is not mocked by default on react native's jest setup file.
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/NativeAnimatedHelper');
//jest.mock('react-navigation', () => ({withNavigation: component => component}));

describe('Test', () => {
  test('rendering a component that uses withNavigation', () => {
    const {getByTestId} = render(
      <Test navigation={navigation}></Test>,
    );
    expect(getByTestId('test').toBeDefined());
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance, if anyone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
jest.mock('react-navigation', () => ({
  withNavigation: (Component) => (props) => (
    <Component navigation={{ navigate: jest.fn() }} {...props} />
  ),
}))
```

Tell me if it works for you too.

Comment: Thank a lot for your reply. Do you include above code directly in the test file?

Comment: Yes, put this before your 'describe('Test') etc', on you test file. :)